# Angular directive and method from outer scope don't work

Tags: angularjs

I don't understand why it doesn't work.

I have this method in my controller:

```
    $scope.TestFunc = function () {

        alert("TestFunc called");
    }
```

This is my html:

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-column" print-button-spinner  test="TestFunc()" >
    test
 </button>
```

This is in my directive:

```
App.directive('printButtonSpinner', function() {
    return {
        scope:
        {
            docType: '@',
            test: '&'
        },

        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element) {
            var printFunc = scope.test();
            element.bind('click', printFunc);
        }
    };
});
```

1. When I load my page this method fires automatically. I don't understand why this is happening.
2. When I click the button this method is bonded to, I get the next message in browser console:

   ```
   TypeError: eventFns[i] is undefined
   eventFns[i].call(element, event);
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks for your answers!

**The second part of the question:**

I need to call my controller method:

```
 var printFn = function (docType, element) {/*some code*/}
```

I need to call it from my directive:

```
 <button class="btn btn-default btn-column" print-button-spinner doc-type="zebraCurLabels" print="printFn(docType, null)">
 </button>
```

My directive:

```
 App.directive('printButtonSpinner', function() {
        return {
            scope:
            {
                docType: '@',
                print: '&'
            },

            restrict: 'A',

            link: function (scope, element) {
                var print = scope.test;
                element.bind('click', print(scope.docType, element));
            }
        };
    });
```

Browser console shows the next message:

```
TypeError: eventFns[i] is undefined
eventFns[i].call(element, event);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change this  `var printFunc = scope.test();` to  `var printFunc = scope.test;` test itself a function name.

> When I load my page this method fires automatically. I don't
>   understand why this is happening.

So if you use scope.test() it will call your `TestFunc` and assign result to `printFunc` which is null because it is not returning anything.

It causes your problem one

> When I click the button this method is binded to, I get the next
>   message in browser console: TypeError: eventFns[i] is undefined
>   eventFns[i].call(element, event);

Since click expecting the second argument as a function but you are just giving it a value it throws error.

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3bBi5qvRuVkdlV8zEIOb?p=preview)

Hope it help :)

**UPDATE**

I changed `test: '='` and added `doc-type="doctypeisHTML"`

```
 element.bind('click', function(){
              print(scope.docType, element);
            });
```

[Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/3bBi5qvRuVkdlV8zEIOb?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you! I was inattentive.

Comment: Can I ask you one more question? I couldn't create another one here because of 90 minutes timeout.

Comment: I need to call a method with parameters. What should I do to pass these parameters inside of the method? Situation is the same, but I need to pass two params inside of this method. The first is a string parameter, the second is dom element that I get inside of my directive

Comment: yes, I need this parameters in controller method that I call from my directive

Comment: Hey @yurart I added the updated answer please check :)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/82206/discussion-between-yurart-and-squiroid).